# Do 3D bar charts have advantages over 2D bar charts?

Tags: visualization, reference-request

I vaguely remember that there was a study / blog post which made a strong point against 3D bar charts. Do you have a source at hand which compares the two - 2D bar charts and 3D bar charts?

Comment: How about this simple study http://uxmetricsgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/posterV5.png?

Comment: I would only use 3D charts for 3D data and only in a presentation where the charts would be rotated to show some features of the data in 3D.  Never static 3D charts and never 3D charts on 2-dimensional data.

Answer (score 1):

A relevant source seems to be

> A Psychophysical analysis of chart readability, 2001

Sadly, I don't have access to it.

### Anecdotes

If you have an area chart, giving it a 3D-effect and rotating slightly can help readability. But I don't remember a context where you could not have used a line chart in the first place.

### Bad sources

- PRO: Looks good ([targetdashboard.com](https://www.targetdashboard.com/blog/75/3D-or-not-3D-when-to-add-a-3rd-dimension-to-your-KPI-charts.aspx))
- CON: Values are harder to read from the axes only - you need to add values to
  the bars themselves (targetdashboard.com)